# "Mine alone" or "Mine and mine alone"

Tags: word-usage

I've been taught to avoid using same words in English. But why do native people sometimes use such things below?

> It's mine and mine alone.
>
> Listen to me, and listen well.

Comparing to using "It's mine alone" or "Listen to me well", what kind of vibes(?) do they give?

Comment: You've been taught wrong, or have misunderstood.  So listen now, and listen well: repetition with variation can lend emphasis to a statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a type of repetition for emphasis, called "diacope". It is a rhetorical device used to make an idea clearer or more memorable. It is to be distinguished from the type of repetition found in clumsy writing, which is to be avoided, as you have been taught.

Examples of diacope:

> I can picture in my mind a world without war, a world without hate.
>
> Life is not lost by dying! Life is lost
>   Minute by minute, day by
>   dragging day,

[Repetition](https://literarydevices.net/repetition/)
[Literary and rhetorical devices](http://literary.edublogs.org/)

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't call it "literary".

Comment: The term "literary device" should be interpreted as "device occurring in writing or speech", and not as "occurring in literature of a prestigious or formal type". One finds repetition of this type in advertising, speeches, etc.

Comment: Maybe "rhetorical" would be better.

Comment: Conceded. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Michael Harvey's answer:

The difference between "mine alone" and "mine and mine alone" is the added emphasis that comes from repetition.  How much of an emphasis depends on context.

> The fault is **mine alone**  (I am the one at fault, and no one else)
>
> The fault is **mine and mine alone** (I am the one at fault, no one else, don't even *think* about putting blame elsewhere)

I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo that "mine and mine alone" is more of a *rhetorical* than a *literary* device.  It's fine to use in educated conversation.  However I would say that "mine alone" by itself, definitely has a poetic ring to to it and sounds somewhat *dramatic*.

> "Within the cavern are treasures without measure," the old magician instructed the young tailor, "and of these, the gold, the jewels, the casks of rare spice and incense, you may gather what you can carry. But at the utmost end of the cavern you will find an old lamp, and this you must bring directly back to me, for it is **mine alone**."

Another example of emphasis through repetition is the phrase, "if and only if".  Here there is a slight difference in meaning, as it implies *exclusivity*.

> **If** it's raining, I will wear a raincoat.  (= I might wear a raincoat even if it's not raining, but if it is raining, I'll definitely wear one)
>
> **If and only if** it's raining, I will wear a raincoat (= I will *only* wear a raincoat if it's raining)